# IE9 gives an unwanted padding to DIV containing an IMG when the direction is right-to-left

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-float, right-to-left

I have a div element with 150px width and 1px border, inside another wrapping div. It contains an IMG item with same width, 150px. The direction of wrapping div is right-to-left (the problem occurs when the direction is rtl.)

Problem: When I open my page in IE9, the image-container div has an unwanted padding, and the images falls out of the div from the right side, over the border of the div. The problem goes off and came, in depending on presence or absence of vertical scroll bar.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .wrap {
                width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
                direction: rtl;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .img-container {
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                background: red; /*background to show the problem better*/
            }
            img {
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="img-container";>
            <img  src="my-image.jpg" width="150px"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

And here is the screenshot of the problem:

[image: unwanted padding in IE9]

Is this a known bug? how can I deal with it?